# Redirect url for REST service

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am able to reach my website at a certain ip address and I am going to implement a REST service. I have some PHP files that perform actions on a database and I am calling them from the client. I am using linux ubuntu as server and so far I can do this:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/create/?id=someId&val=someValue
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/delete/?id=someId
```

I can do the above because inside /var/www/html I have a folder called `api` that contains another folder `called` create. The `create` cointains the file index.php so that I can omit it and execute the URL you can see above.

This works fine but I don't think this is the proper way to do it. I am new with this so I don't know what to do. After some researches I have found that my goal probably be achieved using an `.htaccess` file use url rewriting but I am not sure.

How can I do this? Do I have to place all the php files in a single folder and then use an htaccess file? (**^**)

---

(**^**) To be more precise: instead of having this

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/create/index.php?id=someId&val=someValue
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/delete/index.php?id=someId
//and so on with other actions...
```

Do I have to create a folder like

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/files/
```

containing all my php files (create.php, delete.php, view.php...) and the use an htaccess to redirect?

I see that websites offer their api using `www.domain.com/api/something/?data=Value` or `www.domain.com/api/something/dataAbout/`. Are they doing what I have said about the .htaccess? I hope I have well explained my problem.

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/([\w-]+)/?$ files/$1.php [L,NC]
```

This is inside /var/www/html and I have api inside /home/username/api .

Thanks Emma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

1. Create php files in a folder `files/` subdirectory as `create.php`, `delete.php`, `view.php` etc (by renaming each individual `index.php` file, you mentioned).
2. Move away `api` directory somewhere outside site root.

Once that is done use following .htaccess file in `/var/www/html/`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/([\w-]+)/?$ files/$1.php [L,NC]
```

Then use new URLs as:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/create?id=someId&val=someValue
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/delete?id=someId
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) So I am creating php files in /var/www/html/files/ and I put the php files inside here. Then I just have to apply the .htaccess and. Am I correct?

Comment: I have /var/www/html/files/ with inside create.php, delete.php and so on. I also have /var/www/html/other/api but it is not working. Is the htaccess file proper? The htaccess is in /var/www/html/

Comment: Look at my comment above. Then I digit http://192.168.0.216/files/create/ but I have an error. I will check again in 30 minutes :)

Comment: now I have /home/username/api folder and /var/www/html/files folder (inside files there are view.php, create.php and so on). The http://192.168.0.216/api/view doesn't work (the ip is correct, I can see index.html). The .htaccess is in /var/www/html folder. Any idea? I have created the htaccess with 'sudo touch /var/www/html/.htaccess' and edited it with nano. Edits are saved and the file is as you told me :)

Comment: The http://192.168.0.216/files/view.php works fine. The 192.168.0.216/api/view does not, it's a 404. Could it be the htaccess?

Comment: still nothing, 404 even with the edit you made! :( Nevermind, thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: So `http://192.168.0.216/files/view.php` loads fine but `http://192.168.0.216/api/view` gives 404? Can you show your full .htaccess in question.

Comment: I think you are correct now. I have written gsdsRewiteEngine On ... but no 500, I have the 404. I guess that the htaccess is not enabled. Should I edit some config?

Comment: Yes .htaccess needs to be enabled in Apache server config. Every Apache installation is different so you can just google it using your OS and Apache installation on how to enable it.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much for your patience :) I had to edit 000-default.conf and add "<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>". Restart apache and now it works. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

In first, this is not the right way to create a RESTFUL API. My suggestion is to you read a best practices article.

You shouldn't create a CREATE and DELETE folder. You should use HTTP actions.

To create a new record you should use POST. In example, `POST /user` and in the body you pass the user's information.

In another example, you could use the same route by using different HTTP methods: `DELETE /user/1` to delete a user and `PATCH /user/1` to edit some already existent user's information.

Hope it's help you.